# Molality and dissociation

Tags: acid-base, concentration

For $\ce{HCl(aq) -> H^{+}(aq) + Cl^{-}(aq)}$, if $\ce{HCl}$ has a concentration of 1 molar then $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ also have 1 molar. But for $\ce{HF(aq) <=> H^{+}(aq) + F^{-}(aq)}$, if $\ce{HF}$ has a concentration of 1.5 molar, then why doesn't $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{F-}$ have 1.5 molar as well?

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is because $\ce{HF}$ doesn't dissociate as much as $\ce{HCl}$.  Let's examine why this is by introducing some terms like $\ce{pH}$ and $\ce{pK_a}$.

- $\ce{pH}$ does not measure the strength of a given acid, but rather the acidity of a given solution.
- $\ce{pK_a}$ does measure the relative strength of an acid, look at the following equilibrium

$$\ce{H2O + HX<=>H3O^+ + X^-}$$
$$\ce{so~~~K_{eq}=\frac{[H3O^+][X^{-}]}{[H2O][HX]}}$$ but in dilute solutions the concentration of water stays constant so we can rewrite this equation as
$$\ce{K_{a}=\frac{[H3O^+][X^{-}]}{[HX]}}$$ and finally, $$\ce{pK_{a}~=~-Log_{10}K_{a}}$$ Now we can see that the more highly dissociated our acid $\ce{HX}$, the higher the concentrations of $\ce{H3O^+}$ and $\ce{X^{-}}$, and in turn the larger the value for $\ce{K_{a}}$, and the more negative the value of $\ce{pK_{a}}$.

Bottom line: highly dissociated acids have large negative $\ce{pK_{a}}$ values

Now, here is a Table from [SparkNotes](http://www.sparknotes.com/chemistry/acidsbases/fundamentals/section2.rhtml).  It compares the $\ce{pK_{a}s}$ (degree of ionization or strength) of the various haloacids.  You can see that as we move down the Table from $\ce{HF}$ to $\ce{HI}$ the $\ce{pK_{a}}$ becomes much more negative; our acids become much more dissociated in water.  So we see that $\ce{HF}$ is not very dissociated ($\ce{K_{a}=10^{-3.1}}$, equilibrium lies to the left). On the other hand, 1 mole of $\ce{HCl}$ will produce about 1 mole of $\ce{H^+}$ ($\ce{K_{a}=10^{+7}}$, equilibrium lies far to the right).  Note too that the $\ce{pK_{a}s}$ of these acids correlate with their bond strength which makes sense.  As the $\ce{H-X}$ bond gets weaker, it becomes easier for the acid to ionize (dissociate).

[image]

Comment: It is noteworthy, that the acidity of a [HF solution strongly depends on its concentration increasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroflouric_acid#Acidity) due to homoassociation $\ce{2HF <=> [FHF]- + H+}$.

Answer (score 4):

HF isn't a strong acid; its dissociation isn't complete in water, unlike HCl's dissociation.

The reason HF isn't a strong acid while HCl is a strong acid has to do with charge density of the conjugate base. Charge density controls the reactivity of the conjugate base; charge is what governs chemistry and physics.

You'll find that the $\ce{F^-}$ anion is fairly reactive relative to $\ce{Cl^-}$, which, in water, is essentially inert. Both are halogens; both have the same magnitude of charge; the difference is that the fluoride anion is smaller than the chloride anion. Therefore, the real negative charge density on the $\ce{F^-}$ anion is greater than that of the chloride anion, and this effective negative charge density is what drives the reactivity of the fluoride anion. In other words, the below reactions occurs to significant extent due to the concentrated negative charge on the fluoride anion:

$\ce{F^{-} + H_2O <=> HF +HO^-}$

This above reaction is antagonistic to the dissociation of $\ce{HF}$ in water because the above reaction makes more $\ce{HF}$! Note that $\ce{K_{b}(F^{-})}$ $=6.6\cdot 10^{-4}$ while $\ce{K_{b}(Cl^{-})}$ $=8.0\cdot 10^{-21}$! So there you have it; empirical evidence that chloride ion is a very unreactive species in water solution.

You'll find that with the binary halogen acids, as you go down group 7, the acids get stronger. For example, $\ce{HBr}$ is an even stronger acid than the already strong acd, $\ce{HCl}$. This again can be rationalized using effective negative charge density; $\ce{Br^-}$ has the same magnitude of negative charge as $\ce{Cl^-}$ but in the bromide anion the negative charge is spread out over an even larger area, making bromide ion all the less reactive than chloride ion and hydrobromic acid stronger than hydrochloric acid.

I hope this answers your questions and gives you some insight into acids.